# Clone of Closure Updates Original Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to clone board because my minMax function needs a copy of the current board's state every time I run minMax.

I recently converted my es6 Board.js module from a singleton (exporting functions from it) to a closure (function that returns a function because I want to hide state and also take advantages of being able to call my function factory to create new instances of Board.

So right now Board.js looks like this:

**Board.js**

```
function Board() {
  let board = [
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' '];

  function slotIsOpen(position){
    const open = board[position] === ' ';
    return open;
  }

  function getOpenSlots(){
    const openSlots = board.filter((slot) => {
      return slot === ' '
    });
    return openSlots;
  }

  function getBoard() {
    return board;
  }

  function isFull(board){
    const emptySlots = board.filter(slot => { return slot === ' '});
    return emptySlots.length === 0;
  }

  function addMoveToBoard(position, player){
    board.splice(+position, 1, player.marker);
  }

  const api = {
    addMoveToBoard,
    isFull,
    getBoard,
    getOpenSlots,
    slotIsOpen
  };

  return api;
}

export default Board;
```

My **Player.js** that takes in a Board() instance:

```
function Player(board, ai){

  async function move({position = -1, currentPlayer = null}){
    const minMaxBoard = Object.create(board),
      nextMove = await ai.minMax(minMaxBoard, currentPlayer)

    if(nextMove){
      const moved = Move.makeMove(nextMove.openSpaceIndex, currentPlayer, board);
      return moved;
    }
  }

  const player = {
    addPlayer
  };

  return player;
}

export default Player
```

What's happening is this:

`const minMaxBoard = Object.create(board)` -  I create a clone of the board factory (or so I thought) and then send it into my minMax function as a copy of Board().  (keep in mind `board` in `Player(board, ai)` is initially a param I inject into Player.  The caller is simply sending in Board() for that param).

My minMax function utilizes that copy, manipulates it to do some analysis.  That copy again is a copy of board so it's working with whatever the current state of board is without effecting the original board.

After `minMax` is done, my `makeMove` is called:
`const moved = Move.makeMove(nextMove.index, currentPlayer, board);`

The problem is that `board` here should be working with the original board sent into Player.  But I notice that somehow it's lost that reference and is now referencing the minMaxBoard.  Why?

I've also tried `const minMaxBoard = Board();` instead of `const minMaxBoard = Object.create(board);` but then that causes a problem..which is that the minMax function ends up getting a brand new board that's empty...which is not what I want sent into minMax.  I want a copy of the current board sent in which has the current state.

**UPDATE**:

I've changed it to try to provide clone ability but it's still not quite working, I still get a new empty board every time I call clone:

```
function _Board(board) {
  function slotIsOpen(position){
    const open = board[position] === EMPTY_CELL;
    return open;
  }

  function getOpenSlots(){
    const openSlots = board.filter((slot) => {
      return slot === EMPTY_CELL
    });
    return openSlots;
  }

  function getBoard() {
    return board;
  }

  function isFull(board){
    const emptySlots = board.filter(slot => { return slot === EMPTY_CELL});
    return emptySlots.length === 0;
  }

  function addMoveToBoard(position, marker){
    board.splice(position, 1, marker);
  }

  function clone() {
    return Board(board.slice());
  }

  return {
    addMoveToBoard,
    clone,
    isFull,
    getBoard,
    getOpenSlots,
    slotIsOpen
  };
}

function Board() {
  return _Board([
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' ']);
}

export default Board;
```

Then in **Player.js**:

```
const minMaxBoard = board.clone();
const nextMove = await ai.minMax(minMaxBoard, currentPlayer)
```

but I still end up with the same problem, that is the clone ends up with an empty board every time instead of a copy of the current state of `board` which again `board` is an instance `Board()` sent into `Player`.

I also tried `const minMaxBoard = Board(board.getBoard().slice())` but still did not get a copy of the current board array in the new Board.

Comment: `Object.create()` is not an API that clones objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.create` does not clone the object passed into it - rather, it creates a new object whose internal *prototype* is the passed object. If you then proceed to refer to (and possibly mutate) a property that happens to be on the *prototype*, then that will indeed mutate the original prototype.

If you want to have multiple independent copies of a `Board`, you need to explicitly call `Board()` each time, for example:

```
function Player(board, ai){
  async function move({position = -1, currentPlayer = null}){
    // Create an entirely new Board:
    const minMaxBoard = Board();
```

To make copies of an existing board, you might have `Board` accept a parameter of the `board` array to use:

```
const defaultBoard = [
  ' ', ' ', ' ',
  ' ', ' ', ' ',
  ' ', ' ', ' '];
function Board(board = defaultBoard) {
  // ...

// other file:

function Player(board, ai){
  async function move({position = -1, currentPlayer = null}){
    const minMaxBoard = Board(board.getBoard().slice());
```

Comment: well I don't want to expose my private board data like that.  It was suggested for me to provide a clone() method on my API that would internally clone itself somehow

Comment: but thanks for the explanation on the Object.create too

Comment: tried this but I don't quite have it right   function cloneBoard(){
    return Object.assign({board, ...api});
  }

  And I'd expose cloneBoard in my api object that I return from this factory

Comment: Oh, that's right, the board returned by `getBoard` will reference the internal board - you'll have to explicitly copy it first for the new board to have a *copy*. Call `.slice()` on `getBoard()` to make a shallow copy of the array

Comment: well I need a deep copy, how would I go about doing that? and I'm looking more toward doing this `const minMaxBoard = board.clone()` so that the internals are kept internal...board knows how to clone itself, and shouldn't know about player at all cause Player is higher up in the layers of the system

Comment: Your `board` only looks to be an array of primitives, so a shallow copy would be enough. If you *need* a deep copy, you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObjToCopy))`

Comment: I need to clone its current state though..hmm so if it's been updated, I want to be able to clone it's current internal state to a new Board() because minMax will call getBoard() on the clone

Comment: yea by deep copy I mean I want the api methods to be available on the clone

Comment: They will be if you create a new Board: `Board(board.getBoard().slice())` You might consider using `class` or prototypes if you want all instances to share the same methods

Comment: I tried just board.slice() but it's saying slice is not a function

Comment: You need a reference to the array in order to call `.slice` (an array method) - a reference to the board API isn't enough because the board API doesn't have a `slice` method. See my snippet in the answer for an example: `const minMaxBoard = Board(board.getBoard().slice());`

Comment: right I tried that: `const minMaxBoard = Board(board.getBoard().slice())` but still did not get a copy of the current array

Comment: thanks I got it working by tweaking some of mine a bit more.  I really appreciate your help and insight today, I'm still shitty in JS TBH..trying to get over that gap.